# Prevent Ajax Call When there is no session & Network Discoonects in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I  facing two issues in my project.Please help me to rid of those.

1. I am using .load() function in javascript to load the other page
   using Ajax. It's Working great. But if i opened my project in other
   tab and logout and get back to here and try to make ajax call it is
   showing the login page Where i am loading the page using .load()
   function.How do i solve it.
2. How do i stop ajax call when network disconnects ?

how to solve these two issues??

Comment: what you have tried ??... add code here

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is a little complex as you want your Browser (client) to keep a record of weather an active session for the current user exists on the server.

The Problem is that user's Session record is maintained at the server and  you want your client to know the sessions status. You will need to write some java script which will keep calling a function on server after a fixed interval of time to check if the session is valid.

I would do it something like this :

```
// this will call a function to make a request to server and check if session exist's after every 10 seconds.
var t=setInterval(checkSessionExist,10000); 

function checkSessionExist(){
 $.get( "someFunctionToCheckSession", function( data ) {
   if(!data.isSessionActive){
     clearInterval(t);
     alert("Your Session has Expired. Please Login to continue !!");
     location.reload();
   }
});
}
```

On Server Side You will have some method named **someFunctionToCheckSession**

```
function someFunctionToCheckSession(){
  // CHeck user's active session here
  $data['isSessionActive'] = 0;
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
      $data['isSessionActive'] = 1;
  }
  echo json_encode($data); 

}
```

Comment: Actually if there is no session , it won't call that function so it is throwing me an error like unexpected token <

Comment: can you explain in detail ?

Comment: ok,I opened my project in two tabs, if i logout in one of the tab, the session will be destroyed.So if there is no session the GET request will failed.

Comment: you will have to check if the session variable exists. I have made changes Please recheck

Comment: Yeah i know.But if there is no session, we can't do the server request,right?. Whatever you told is correct i,e.if we get 1 from server session exist or if we get 0 session absence.But What i am trying to tell is, how can we get the 0 from server if there is no session that means we can't do server request

Comment: No. That is not true. You can make a request to server that does not require  you to have an active session.

Comment: i didn't get any error while session exist.So there is no problem to get syntax errors.am i correct?

Comment: `function someFunctionToCheckSession(){
  // CHeck user's active session here
  $data['isSessionActive'] = 0;
  if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
      $data['isSessionActive'] = 1;
  }
  echo json_encode($data); 

}`

Comment: client side code:`// this will call a function to make a request to server and check if session exist's after every 10 seconds.
var t=setInterval(checkSessionExist,10000); 

function checkSessionExist(){
 $.get( "<?php echo base_url('workspace/home/someFunctionToCheckSession'); ?>", function( data ) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.isSessionActive);
   if(!data.isSessionActive){
     clearInterval(t);
     alert("Your Session has Expired. Please Login to continue !!");
     location.reload();
   }
});
}`

Comment: can you check the java script console to see if the page is making ajax reqest  to  workspace/home/someFunctionToCheckSession after every 10 seconds and what is the response for that ?

Comment: Yeah I am seeing the whole url what i am calling When session presence. if session not presence it doesn't call and throw an error unexpected token >

Comment: are you testing on localhost or do you have a development server ? can you show me ?

Comment: I am testing on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

i hope this can help

in your function __construct  include this.

if(!$this->session->userdata('somevalue'){redirect('somevalue');}